# video color detection using JavaScript and canvas, but the RGB returns different in Chrome on PC from Chrome on iPhone X

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-video, video-capture

I use the JavaScript and canvas to detect the RGB value on my website, but when I test in the Chrome/Edge, it works fine that the wrapper div background color could match that in the video, but when I test the same code in the Chrome on iPhone X, it comes out they have slightly different.

The MP4 video file seems to have the cross-domain issue here, but the code works fine on the PC as I described, here are the screenshots showing what I met:

- CHROME/PC
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfqbJ.png)
  the wrapper div's background is totally the same as the background in the video.
- CHROME/IPHONE X
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GqTe.png)
  now it's slightly different.

I don't know how to avoid this issue, pls help and thank you!

```js
video = document.getElementById('cat_video');
video.muted = true;
video.autoplay = true;
video.loop = true;
video.setAttribute('defaultMuted', '');
video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');

function setVideoBgColor(vid, backgroundElement) {
  const ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  //size of canvas space to copy pixel onto
  videoWidth = 400;
  videoHeight = 300;
  canvas.width = videoWidth * ratio;
  canvas.height = videoHeight * ratio;
  canvas.style.width = `${videoWidth}px`;
  canvas.style.height = `${videoHeight}px`;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.scale(ratio, ratio);
  ctx.drawImage(vid, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  const p = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 100, 100).data;
  const colorBoost = 0;
  const colorR = p[0] + colorBoost;
  const colorG = p[1] + colorBoost;
  const colorB = p[2] + colorBoost;
  //colorLayer.data[pixelPos];
  backgroundElement.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + colorR + "," + colorG + "," + colorB + ")";
}
document.getElementById('cat_video').addEventListener("play", function() {
  setVideoBgColor(document.getElementById('cat_video'), this.parentElement);
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-item: center;
  justify-item: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  background: pink;
}

#cat_video {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video id="cat_video" src="https://www.purrfectland.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/mouse_playing_cat.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: No IphoneX to test with... **(1)** Can you confirm (via `console.log()` or `alert()`) the said values of colorR , colorG and colorB as told by iPhone? **(2)** The color shades on PC are a different number to the two shades of blue that you get on iPhoneX. So you actually have three types of blue going on between those above 2 pictures.

Comment: yes, you are right, I have checked all the RGB colors from PC and IPHONE X, they are differnt indeed, but since my code is getting the RGB from the video, then why the color got from the video in the IPHONE X is such a big different from that of the video?

Comment: I think its because video colors are stored in YUV but displayed in Standard RGB (or sRGB), then also by default Apple devices use Apple RGB format. So it's possible the video tag is showing **sRGB** colorspace but the CSS is using**AppleRGB** colorspace. I needed the given numbers to help make a calculation to re-fix the CSS values.

Comment: hi, VC.One, I pick out the color here [link](https://snipboard.io/jVIgfS.jpg)

Comment: rgb(50, 118, 157) for the wrapper background, and rgb(46, 108, 147) is in the video of the Iphone, I use the Iphone screenshot to capture these values, I have no idea where they would be transformed again or not..thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry for the suspense. Okay so does setting the CSS background color to `rgb( 42, 98, 137 )` help to now match the video's bg color? **PS**: I got a formula to convert to/from AppleRGB and sRGB, it works okay for Red and Green parts but stuck on the Blue part. Your feedback might be final piece to solve this question.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply, and now the color turns out to be [link](https://snipboard.io/3B27Wp.jpg), I have set the wrapper color to rgb( 42, 98, 137 ), but the background color doesn't look the same as the previous test. the test page is here[link](https://www.lifeofcar.com/test/test.html), thank you.

Comment: I think you'll just have to `console.log( "color is  : " + colorR + "," + colorG + "," + colorB);` and see if your colors are transformed. **PS:** Your video colors sRGB `(46, 108, 147)` transform into AppleRGB as `(50, 118, 157)`... But AppleRGB `(46, 108, 147)` will become sRGB `(53, 126, 162)`. That's why you must **double-check** (via logging) what RGB numbers are **actually being given** to CSS as background color. What are the numbers for `colorR` and so on...? From there you can calculate the "transform" offsets.  **PPS** Your video's first pixel is not the majority BG color (zoom in).

Comment: I have alerted the color values, which are:
iPhone X
[Video background color detected](https://snipboard.io/YF3VZC.jpg)
[Video background color applied](https://snipboard.io/pQl4Je.jpg)

iPhone 7
[Video background color detected](https://snipboard.io/lZtqHN.jpg)
[Video background color applied](https://snipboard.io/T3fy2e.jpg)

PC chrome 
on desktop, it works fine, [link](https://snipboard.io/Yr9Sp5.jpg)

Comment: and I have searched for some info that on the desktop the image color applies sRGB, but the color in the video of mp4 format would be applied in different color spaces for the video compression. as I was using the canvas to capture the video pixels which are from REC.601(i am not sure whether was 601). the color difference that occurred on iOS would only happen during the video-canvas transformation, right?